# webview keeps crashing application

Tags: qt, webview, qml

i'm working on a qml application that renders webview content via a navigation drawer. in the drawer there are:

```
model: ListModel {
    ListElement {title: "<img src=\"qrc:/images/portal.png\" align=\"middle\"/>   SU Portal"; source:"qrc:/Portal.qml"}
    ListElement {title: "<img src=\"qrc:/images/website.png\" align=\"middle\"/>   SU Website"; source: "qrc:/Website.qml"}
    ListElement {title: "<img src=\"qrc:/images/airtime.png\" align=\"middle\"/>   Purchase Airtime"; source: "qrc:/Airtime.qml"}
}
```

and in portal.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import Qt.labs.controls 1.0
import QtWebView 1.1


Pane {
    id: pane

    WebView {
        id: portal
        url: "http://portal.salemuniversity.edu.ng"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

}
```

i tried putting it in an item and window but it stil crashed. i'm stuck

Comment: did u find solution ??

Comment: @noone I did find it

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseSoftwareOpenGL);
```

to your `main.cpp` , at the beginning.